# Way to change locale on rails validation messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby 3.1.3, rails 7.0.4

I have a simple uniqueness validation in model:

app/models/user.rb

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true
```

app/controllers/user_controller.rb

```
user = User.new
user.email = 'existed_email@example.com'
user.save
```

config/locales/en-US.yml

```
en-US:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: email
  errors:
    format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
    messages:
      taken: has already been taken
```

config/locales/ja-JP.yml

```
ja-JP:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: メールアドレス
  errors:
    format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
    messages:
      taken: はすでに存在します。
```

When I tried to create a user with existed email to try to get the error message it automatically gave me the english version of the error message, which is

```
email has already been taken
```

Even though the default language is japanese (I18n.default_locale = :ja-JP). How do I change the locale dynamically when creating the user in controller? Something like

```
user.save(lang: 'ja-JP')
return user.errors.full_messages => this should output ["メールアドレス はすでに存在します"]

user.save(lang: 'en-US')
return user.errors.full_messages => this should output ["email has already been taken"]
```

How does rails decide what language to use? I have not set the locale anywhere in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
ja-JP:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: メールアドレス
              invalid: メールアドレス
```

Below is the example for dynamic message text.

Controller or helper code:

```
err_message = t('coupons.redeemed_html', count: 2, limit: 1)
```

locales file:

```
jp:
 coupons:
   redeemed_html:
     one: '%{count}/<span class="limit">%{limit}</span>'
```

**If you want to change locale for the save action**

```
I18n.with_locale(:ja) {user.save}
```

Above code will not change the default locale for the user.

**Setting the Locale from User Preferences:**
An application with authenticated users may allow users to set a locale preference through the application's interface. With this approach, a user's selected locale preference is persisted in the database and used to set the locale for authenticated requests by that user. Doc Doc Here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

```
around_action :switch_locale

def switch_locale(&action)
  locale = current_user.try(:locale) || I18n.default_locale
  I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)
end
```

Comment: It's not just the japanese message that I want. I want the error message to be dynamically changed accordingly to the language I need when `user.save` is called. Is there anything I can put in model or controller to achieve it?

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. I've updated the question to show the desired output.

Comment: Updated the answer. Doc is here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: **Do not set the locale with `I18n.locale = :ja`**! Its not thread safe. Instead use `I18n.with_locale(:ja) { &action }` in a callback. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-a-locale

Comment: @max I have updated the answer. Thanks for the thread safe point.

Comment: Np. The same approach applies no matter if your setting the locale from user preferences, URI paths, subdomains or even headers.

Comment: I18n.with_locale does the trick. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

[with_locale](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#managing-the-locale-across-requests) should do the trick.

```
# app/controllers/user_controller.rb

I18n.with_locale(:en) do
  ...
  user.save
end
```

Note that the fact that your `I18n.default_locale` is set to jp, but the error you receive is still in English suggests that you're also setting `I18n.locale = ...` somewhere in the code.